# How can i convert HTML to string.Format

Tags: css, string, html, stringbuilder

**I have base code in HTML and i want convert this code to string Format.**

```
<table id="rounded-corner" summary="2007 Major IT Companies' Profit" style="text-align: center">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-company"></th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded">Název</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded">Web</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded">Popis</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded">Edit</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q4">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
```

**and i want this HTML use to string.Format.**

```
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
data.Append(string.Format(@"<table id="rounded-corner" summary="2007 Major IT Companies' Profit" style="text-align: center">
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th scope="col" class="rounded-company"></th>
             <th scope="col" class="rounded">Název</th>
             <th scope="col" class="rounded">Web</th>
             <th scope="col" class="rounded">Popis</th>
             <th scope="col" class="rounded">Edit</th>
             <th scope="col" class="rounded-q4">Delete</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>"));
```

I have problem with this symbol "" for string.Format, can you help me how can i do it.

Comment: just use back slash to ignore the double quotes. Something line `<table name= \"something\" >`

Comment: I agree with @NayanaAdassuriya.. The \ specifies that it is not the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `\"` like this:

```
string.Format(@"<table id=\"rounded-corner\" summary=\"2007 Major IT Companies' Profit\" style=\"text-align: center\">
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th scope=\"col\" class=\"rounded-company\"></th>
             <th scope=\"col\" class=\"rounded\">Název</th>
             <th scope=\"col\" class=\"rounded\">Web</th>
             <th scope=\"col\" class=\"rounded\">Popis</th>
             <th scope=\"col\" class=\"rounded\">Edit</th>
             <th scope=\"col\" class=\"rounded-q4\">Delete</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>")
```

OR you can have `'` like this:

```
string.Format(@"<table id='rounded-corner' summary='2007 Major IT Companies Profit' style='text-align: center'>
        <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th scope='col' class='rounded-company'></th>
                 <th scope='col' class='rounded'>Název</th>
                 <th scope='col' class='rounded'>Web</th>
                 <th scope='col' class='rounded'>Popis</th>
                 <th scope='col' class='rounded'>Edit</th>
                 <th scope='col' class='rounded-q4'>Delete</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>")
```

Comment: thx result from you and krisdy is works thx, but i will use your result because its clearer

Answer (score 0):

For every `"` inside the HTML make it `""`:

```
<table id=""rounded-corner"" summary=""2007 Major IT Companies' Profit"" style=""text-align: center"">
<thead>
     <tr>
         <th scope=""col"" class=""rounded-company""></th>
         <th scope=""col"" class=""rounded"">Název</th>
         <th scope=""col"" class=""rounded"">Web</th>
         <th scope=""col"" class=""rounded"">Popis</th>
         <th scope=""col"" class=""rounded"">Edit</th>
         <th scope=""col"" class=""rounded-q4"">Delete</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```